# What to call the distribution of the square of a zero-mean normal variable plus a constant

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, density-estimation

What is the name of such type of distribution/density function x which is

$x=\theta +u^2$ for $u\sim N(0,\sigma^2$)?

Comment: @Ferdi It's not the distribution that gets squared, it's the variable.

Comment: @Dothis It's a special case of a shifted gamma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a special case of a shifted gamma.

$U^2\sim \text{Gamma}(\frac12,2\sigma^2)$ (shape-scale parameterization)

and so $U^2+\theta$ is shifted-gamma (or three-parameter gamma*); $\theta$ is called the shift-parameter (or sometimes the threshold parameter). You might write it as $\text{shifted-gamma}(\frac12,2\sigma^2,\theta)$.

* however it's not the only distribution to be called "three-parameter gamma"

Other names: Pearson type III, scaled-shifted-chi-squared(1).

Comment: This is very great explanation. Thank you so much. Then I have one more question. I have also such a function $f(x; \theta)=exp(-(x-\theta)) $ for $-infinite <\theta <infinite $ and $\theta \le x < infinite$ These two forms are the same, or different?

Comment: That's a shifted (standard-) exponential; it's a *different* special case of the shifted gamma. A shifted-gamma$(1,1,θ)$